# I am having issues with the scanner not recognizing certain characters

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to programming and have never used scanner before. I am having issues with the scanner not recognizing certain characters or at least that is what I think the issue is. The program that I have to make should compute the intersection, union, and set difference of two sets of non-negative integers. The user should input two sets separated by commas, and enclosed in square brackets. For example: [1, 2, 3] + [4, 3, 10, 0]. I was also asked to use TreeSets, and use the appropriate TreeSet method to perform the requested operation on the two sets. At the moment the output that I receive is:

Enter a list of non-negative integers, separated by commas, and enclosed in square brackets.
For example: [1, 2, 3] + [4, 3, 10, 0].

Enter Sequences: [0,1,2,3]+[4,5,6]
Error in input: Expected '[' at start of set.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;  
public class setCalculator {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    

    
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        
        System.out.println("Enter a list of non-negative integers, separated by commas, and enclosed in square brackets.  ");
         
        System.out.println("For example: [1, 2, 3] + [4, 3, 10, 0]. ");
 
        
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter Sequences: ");
            if(input.hasNext("\n")) {
                break;
            } try {
                compute();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Error in input: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            input.next();
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void compute(){
        
         TreeSet<Integer> setA, setB;  // The two sets of integers.
         
         setA = readSet();
        if (! input.hasNext("\\+") && ! input.hasNext("\\-") && ! input.hasNext("\\*"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected *, +, or  - after first set.");
        setB = readSet();
        if( input.hasNext("\n"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Extra unexpected input.");
        if(input.hasNext("\\+"))
            setA.addAll(setB);     // Union.
         else if (input.hasNext("\\*"))
            setA.retainAll(setB);  // Intersection.
         else
            setA.removeAll(setB);  // Set difference.
         
         System.out.print("Value:  " + setA);
         
         /*
          * Start with an empty set.
Read the '[' that begins the set.
Repeat:
   Read the next number and add it to the set.
   If the next character is ']':
      break.
   Read the comma that separates one number from the next.
Read the ']'.
Return the set.
          */
    }
    
    private static TreeSet<Integer> readSet() {     
        TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        if(! input.hasNext("\\[")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected '[' at start of set.");
            
        }
        if(input.hasNext("\\[")){
            input.nextLine();
            return set;
        }
        while (true) {
            // Read the next integer and add it to the set.
         
         if (! input.hasNextInt())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected an integer.");
         int n = input.nextInt(); // Read the integer.
         set.add(Integer.valueOf(n));  // (Could have just said set.add(n)!)
         if (input.hasNext("\\)"))
            break;  // ']' marks the end of the set.
         else if (input.hasNext("\\,"))
            input.next(); // Read a comma and continue.
         else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected ',' or ']'.");
      }

        input.next(); // Read the ']' that ended the set.

      return set;
}
}
```

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to stackoverflow! Have you tried debugging this example to see what is happening. The debugger is your friend, learn it early and it will be a great ally in your programming adventure. Also, please consider how you could reduce the question to show a minimal example that will help others to better understand the issue. See the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @wobr, thank you for your response and the link to the advice. I have tried using the debugger, from using the debugger the issue seems to be in the readSet() method but I am not 100% sure that is why I added the whole program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue probably lies in your usage of `Scanner.hasNext()`. Especially on `if(input.hasNext("\\[")){`. If I'm not mistaken, this will check against the complete token, which is clearly more than only the "[".

Overall, your approach is overcomplicating the issue. I personally would not work through the whole task with the scanner. It's easier to simply take the input from the scanner and then do the input validation on the retrieved String.

This short snippet will take the input from the scanner, save it in a String and parse the `Set`s from the provided String. (But there is definitely a more efficient solution possible)

**Edit:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the sequence:");
    // read the whole input
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    // find the operator
    String op = findOperator(input);
    // split the String on "+"
    String[] sets = input.split("\\" + op);
    if (sets.length != 2) {
        // raise exception for incorrect input
        return;
    }
    TreeSet<Integer> setA = parseSet(sets[0]);
    TreeSet<Integer> setB = parseSet(sets[1]);
    TreeSet<Integer> resultSet = computeResultSet(setA, setB, op);
    System.out.println(resultSet);
}

private static String findOperator(String input) {
    char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*' };
    for (char c : operators) {
        if (input.indexOf(c) != -1) {
            return "" + c;
        }
    }
    // operator not found -> wrong input -> exception handling
    return "";
}

private static TreeSet<Integer> parseSet(String input) {
    TreeSet<Integer> outputSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    // remove whitespaces
    input = input.trim();
    // check if the input has the correct format
    if (!input.startsWith("[") || !input.endsWith("]")) {
        // exception for incorrect input
        return outputSet;
    }
    // remove the braces
    input = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1);
    // add the integers to the set
    String[] digits = input.split(",");
    for (String singleDigit : digits) {
        outputSet.add(Integer.parseInt(singleDigit.trim()));
    }
    return outputSet;
}

private static TreeSet<Integer> computeResultSet(TreeSet<Integer> setA, TreeSet<Integer> setB, String op) {
    TreeSet<Integer> resultSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    if (op.equals("+")) {
        setA.addAll(setB);
    } else if (op.equals("-")) {
        setA.removeAll(setB);
    } else if (op.equals("*")) {
        setA.retainAll(setB);
    }
    resultSet = setA;
    return resultSet;
}
```

Input:

```
Enter the sequence:
[1,2,3] - [2,3]
```

Output:

```
[1]
```

Comment: Hi @maloomeister, thank you for your response. The code snippet that you have provided works. I have been trying to use what you have shared with the compute method from my post to get the output below but I still can't get it to work.
Input                                         Output
-------------------------                     -------------------
[1, 2, 3] + [3, 5, 7]                      [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
[10,9,8,7] * [2,4,6,8]                   [8]
[ 5, 10, 15, 20 ] - [ 0, 10, 20 ]     [5, 15]

Comment: Ah now I see what you are trying to do. You are using the operator as an indicator on what the sets should look like. That's not part of my response as of now. Let me update it.